# Update UINavigationController when clicked on menu

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, segue

[image]

This is my current storyboard.
I have an initial view (Activity) embedded into a Navigation Controller, which has a top left navigation item (barely visible button) which segues to a menu (Guillotine Menu View Controller) with different options. How do I set this up to open a different ViewController embedded in the same navigation controller when I click on an option in the menu?

BTW I am using [this](https://github.com/Yalantis/GuillotineMenu) library as the menu view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follow:

1. New your different view controller in the storyboard.
2. Cmd+drag from the button to the view controller.
3. In the pop-up menu, select the "push" segue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
I tried doing that and besides push segues being labelled as deprecated, I get this error which crashes the app when I click on the button that segues to the new view: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.', which I think happens because the menu is not embedded into the NavigationController

Comment: I don't know what's the case before see your code and in iOS8, the push segue is replaced with showViewController or showDetailViewController

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a way to make the menu push new viewcontroller to the navigation controller that presented it. I have an idea but I can't try it now, you can try it and tell me if anything isn't clear

1- Add delegate properety to your GuillotineMenuViewController

2- In prepareForSegue in your viewcontrollers if the segue is for displaying the menu, set the menu delegate to self

3- Make menu buttons' actions call the menu's delegate with the name (or better the storyboard ID) of the viewcontroller it should push

4- In the delegate function close the menu, and check if the viewcontroller isn't the one already on top, instantiate it with the corresponding storyboard ID and push it